# Why can't I consume the users data from context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am trying to understand context-api , when I console.log(users) in CardTemplate file all the saved data is showing, but i need that data in UserProfile.jsx, but I am failing to consume the users data...
UserContext.js

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext({
  user: {
    userId: "@abhinav011",
    bio: `Use our Card to provide a flexible and extensible content container based on Tailwind CSS with multiple variants and options.`,
    img: `https://picsum.photos/id/123/40/40`
  },
  setUsers: (users) => {}
});

export const useUser = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};

export const UserProvider = UserContext.Provider;
```

CardTemplate.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import like from "../assets/like.png";
import liked from "../assets/liked.png";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useUser } from "../context/UserContext";
import { UserProvider } from "../context/UserContext";

import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardFooter,
  Typography,
  Button,
} from "@material-tailwind/react";
import { useState } from "react";
export const CardTemplate = ({ userId, tweet, likeCountPrev, img }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({});
  const [likeCount, setLikeCount] = useState(likeCountPrev);
  const [isLike, setIsLike] = useState(false);
  const handelLike = (e) => {
    if (!isLike) {
      e.target.src = liked;
      setLikeCount((prev) => prev + 1);
      setIsLike(true);
    } else {
      e.target.src = like;
      setLikeCount((prev) => prev - 1);
      setIsLike(false);
    }
  };

  const handleUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUsers({
      userId,
      bio: tweet,
      img,
    });
  };

  return (
    <UserProvider value={{ users, setUsers }}>
      <div>
        <Card className="mt-6 w-80 m-5 ring-1 shadow-black ring-gray-400 min-h-fit">
          <CardBody>
            <Link to="userprofile" onClick={handleUser}>
              <Typography variant="h5" color="blue-gray" className="mb-2 flex">
                <img
                  src={img}
                  alt=""
                  srcset=""
                  className="rounded-full mr-2 ring-2 ring-black"
                  width={30}
                  height={30}
                />
                {userId}
              </Typography>
            </Link>
            <Typography>{tweet}</Typography>
          </CardBody>
          <CardFooter className="pt-0 flex">
            <img
              src={like}
              alt=""
              srcset=""
              onClick={handelLike}
              width={24}
              height={24}
            />
            <h3 className="pl-3">{likeCount}</h3>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </UserProvider>
  );
};
```

UserProfile.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useUser } from "../context/UserContext";
export const UserProfile = () => {
  const { users } = useUser();
  const img = users.img;
  const userId = users.userId;
  const bio = users.bio;
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <img src="" alt="" className="rounded-full ring-4 ring-black m-4" />
      <div className="p-4 flex flex-col m-auto ">
        <ul className="flex flex-col items-start">
          <li className="mb-4">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-sans font-bold">{userId}</h1>
          </li>
          <li className="mb-4">
            <p>Abhinav N B</p>
          </li>
          <li className="mb-4">
            <p className="text-start">{bio}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My idea was to set all the user data in context API when user clicks the CardTemplate and access that details in the UserProfile. but 'users' is showing undefined. I am new to React, can some one help with this..

My idea was to set all the user data in context API when user clicks the CardTemplate and access that details in the UserProfile. but 'users' is showing undefined. I am new to React, can some one help with this..?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** It is because `UserProfile` isn't wrapped inside any context provider at all. In order to achieve your desired result, both `CardTemplate` and `UserProfile` need to be wrapped inside the same context provider.

**Detail:** Let me change the code a little bit so you can understand the concept easier.

First, let's create a `Wrapper` component. It only renders the `UserProvider` and `CardTemplate` is `Wrapper`'s direct child:

```
export const Wrapper = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({
    // Some code to set up the user object
  })
  return (
    <UserProvider value={{ users, setUsers }}>
      <CardTemplate />
    </UserProvider>
  )
}
```

Then depends on your need, now you can render `UserProfile` as the child of `CardTemplate` like this:

```
export const CardTemplate = ({ userId, tweet, likeCountPrev, img }) => {
  return (
    <div>
       {/* Some other React code */}
       <CardTemplate />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or as sibling of `CardTemplate` like this:

```
export const Wrapper = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({
    // Some code to set up the user object
  })
  return (
    <UserProvider value={{ users, setUsers }}>
      <CardTemplate />
      <UserProfile />
    </UserProvider>
  )
}
```

In both case, inside `CardTemplate` you can set `user` information

```
const { user, setUsers } = useContext(useUser)
setUsers({
  // Some code to set value of the user
})
```

And the new value which was set in `CardTemplate` will be available in `UserProfile`

```
const { user, setUsers } = useContext(useUser)
// Will log undefined at first, before CardTemplate sets data
// But then will log again with whatever data that CardTemplate sets. 
console.log(user)
```